# Building packages from source on Arch linux

Tags: linux, make, autotools

I've recently set up Arch linux on my desktop PC as a project over the summer, and I'm trying to figure out how to install programs from source. From what I've gathered I have to get the tarball file, extract it, run ./configure, then make, and make-install. I can get past the ./configure, but when I try to run the make command for a codeblocks install I get what looks like a whole bunch of compiler errors.

According to the guide on the codeblocks wiki I have to install wxGTK2-2.8.12 before I can install codeblocks itself, and it tells me to run

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 --enable-xrc --enable-monolithic --enable-unicode
```

Which to me seems to work alright, [here](https://pastebin.com/1Hycc6Bn) is the terminal output.

I then try to run make from the same folder, and the output is really extensive, so sorry if it a pain to read, but the errors are at the end, just not sure whether you will need to see the previous outputs, so [here](https://pastebin.com/NMR4WMuR) is the entire make output.

Comment: Your problem concerns a C++ compilation failure. To attract the
readers most likely to help with a C++ problem always tag your question
**C++**. Similarly for any other programming language.

Comment: For some reason I didn't think of that, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the compile errors in your build log are of the form:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘ddd’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

There are a great many other compiler diagnostics but they are all warnings - not
errors - that you can live with.

The errors arise from the fact that `wxGTK2-2.8.12` - released March, 2011 -
was written to be compiled to an earlier C++ standard (C++98, i.e. C++ 1998)
than the standard that is the default for your `g++` compiler, now in July 2017.
Your compiler I assume is `g++` 6 or later, which defaults to C++14 (C++ 2014).
Since the C++11 standard, the narrowing conversion that is breaking your build
has been ruled ill-formed, which previously it was not.

You can direct `g++` to compile according to the C++ standard of your choice by
passing it the option `-std={c++98|c++03|c++11|c++14|c++17}`, and you can
pass your choice to the `wxGTK2-2.8.12` `configure` script by including it in
the value of the `CXXFLAGS` parameter for `./configure`. Either of `-std=c++98`
or `-std=c++03` will remove the narrowing conversion errors, e.g.

```
../configure CXXFLAGS=-std=c++03 --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 --enable-xrc --enable-monolithic --enable-unicode
```

Alternatively you might simply direct `g++` to suppress the diagnostics denoted by
`-Wnarrowing`:

```
../configure CXXFLAGS=-Wno-narrowing --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 --enable-xrc --enable-monolithic --enable-unicode
```

The `./configure` script of any GNU autotools package (such as you are trying to
build) will have parameters including:

```
CC          C compiler command
CFLAGS      C compiler flags
LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
          nonstandard directory <lib dir>
CPPFLAGS    C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if you have
          headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
CPP         C preprocessor
CXX         C++ compiler command
CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
```

that are there to help you correct for deviations between your toolchain and
the defaults that were expected by the package maintainers when they released the
package. See `./configure --help`.